# Adding tags to Answers in the user page

Tags: feature-request, tags

In the users page, I can see all the questions and answers.

In the questions I can see the tags, but why can't I see the tags in the answers?

I think answers should have the tags!

EDIT:

When I say 'I think answers should have the tags!'

I mean the tags of the question it answers, not new tags. If I am looking through a user's answer list I might find some more interesting answers if I have the tags of the question it answers.

I repeat: I want the tags of the question it answers, not tags related to the answer itself.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why should answers have tags?

Comment: ahh, NOW I get it. Thank you John! :)

Comment: Wait, wait, wait, Jeff! You edited a 10 hours old comment? **THAT'S NOT FAIR!**

Comment: YES!  That's what I meant (pictured above) in my duplicate question.  If somebody else is browsing my profile, or vice-versa, and they look at the answer list, they can have a better idea of what the original question was about (the titles of questions often suck).  I.e. - I am interested in X, do you have any sense when it comes to X?  Where are the answers you have related to X?

Answer (score 1):

You know you can click on the tags on a user page, and see all questions *and answers* that user has ever provided in that tag, right?

Comment: Nope. Didn't know that. Still think it would be nice to see the tags of the answers.