# Votes? Tags on "answers" list on user profile?

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding tags to Answers in the user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34017/adding-tags-to-answers-in-the-user-page)

Just to drive Joel crazy, would it be a useful enhancement to show on the user profile page:

By each answer, show that subject tags for the question to which the answer belonged?

You have no control over the title of a question, so it can be hard for somebody browsing your profile to know to what exactly an answer related without clicking on each to read the question.

Make sense?  It's minty fresh, and wafer thin!

Comment: Sounds like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34017/adding-tags-to-answers-in-the-user-page

Comment: Ouch, it was a duplicate.  See the other question (in above comment) for pretty pictures, as well as the rationale.

Answer (score 2):

First there was the wall of text, then came the wall of tags. Why would you want to see hundreds upon hundreds of tags? Think of the clutter, think of the baby seals! Anyway, you really don't gain much information from that; you can already see what tags you're active on and just following the link to your answer will show you all the tags you can ever want.

Comment: oops.  dup question.  See the questino "John Smithers" references.